# Apache server "Error" message

Tags: apache, joomla, backup, joomla3.8

I'm using an Apache webserver to develop a project using joomla.

Some days ago I did a backup restoration in Joomla (using Akeeba Backups) and now, whenever I try accessing, both the site's backend and frontend, I get a blank page with nothing but the word "Error".

I don't know if the backup is in anyway related to this error as I'm not that much experienced, but I haven't touched the server since then. Any help? How can I find the error's origin?

Comment: Hi, try to pass php in debug mod (php.ini, display_errors on). And check apache logs in /var/log/apache2

Comment: Hi @Kilian, how to I do that? Do I need direct access to the server?

Comment: If you're not in local environnement, yes you have to access to the server who host your apache